# Quota management for indexeddb for subdomain

Tags: indexeddb

Can I have different databases for subdomains without considering one size with another Means size limit for domain and subdomain should be seperate

I have stored 50MB(max-limit) in domain.Without consider this,can I store 50Mb in subdomain.Can anyone pls answer me which will be more helpful for me

Thanks

Comment: indexedDB is a database that runs within a browser. Databases correspond to origins. A url representing a subdomain and a url representing a domain are from different origins, so the databases will be separate. Database storage size is determined by browser settings. The statement "50MB max limit" does not make any sense.

Comment: ok.Thank you so much

Comment: Is it certain that Safari browser support max 50 MB? Will data be stored more than that in safari?